# R: Filling matrix with ones after two zeros

Tags: r

I have this matrix `coef=matrix(c(0),nrow=value)` which is a 10x1 matrix.
I want to fill it with ones after every two zero(0) positions. To be more clear it should be like this:

```
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    1
 [4,]    1
 [5,]    0
 [6,]    0
 [7,]    1
 [8,]    1
 [9,]    0
[10,]    0
```

So after two zeros there are two ones. 
I did this without a loop, which is very simple, what could I use to do fill every 2 positions with ones.
Here is the simple code so far:

```
value=10
coef=matrix(c(0),nrow=value)
coef[1]=0
coef[2]=0
coef[3]=1
coef[4]=1
coef[5]=0
coef[6]=0
coef[7]=1
coef[8]=1
coef[9]=0
coef[10]=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. Why don't you just create the corresponding matrix directly? Instead of creating a 10x1 zero-matrix and then replacing entries.

```
matrix(rep(c(0, 1), each = 2, length.out = 10), nrow = 10)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    1
# [4,]    1
# [5,]    0
# [6,]    0
# [7,]    1
# [8,]    1
# [9,]    0
#[10,]    0
```